# Unexpected (to me) SQL Results When Dividing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get results dividing a calculated value (conditional sum) by another calculated value (count of a total). Results are always outputting as 0. I've double-checked the raw data and wouldn't expect this to be happening. Here is the query in its current state:

```
SELECT 
BUCKET, 
SUM(CASE WHEN RANDOM_ACTUAL>=RANDOM_BENCHMARK_LOW THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) AS CALCULATION 
FROM DATA_TEAM_COLD_CALL_RESULTS 
GROUP BY BUCKET
```

I've also tried using IFF instead of case and querying both from a sub-query. The queries are being run in Periscope from a SQL Server 2012 database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: just from looking at it random_action is not greater than or equal to random_benchmark_low as 0/X = 0

Comment: Try `select (2/3), (2.0/3), (cast(2 as float)/3)` and you'll understand what's happening with that query.

Comment: Thanks at ton... very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting integer division, need to add a decimal place to force a decimal result, easiest to multiply by 1.0 for this:

```
SELECT BUCKET
      , SUM(CASE WHEN RANDOM_ACTUAL>=RANDOM_BENCHMARK_LOW THEN 1 ELSE 0 END *1.0)/COUNT(*) AS CALCULATION 
       FROM DHCSource.dbo.DATA_TEAM_COLD_CALL_RESULTS 
GROUP BY BUCKET
```

Comment: Or just use decimals in the case when and avoid the multiplication `...then 1.0 else 0.0 end) ...` ;)

Comment: @LukStorms Good point, I always think of multiplying because it's often a field rather than hard coded values.